# Finding the bound where the eigenvalues stay.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, systems-of-equations

Let $\lambda = x+iy$. Assume that all matrix in this question are of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\
\bar{b} & \bar{a}
\end{pmatrix}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$.
Consider I have the following set of recursive equation:

$$G_m = -\left(q+\alpha_m\Sigma_w\circ G_m + \sum_{i\neq m}\alpha_i\Sigma_b\circ G_i\right)^{-1}$$

for all $m=1,\cdots,N$ where $q = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & \epsilon\\
\epsilon & \bar{\lambda}\end{pmatrix}$ , $\Sigma_w = \begin{pmatrix} w_1 & w_2\\
w_2 & w_1
\end{pmatrix}$, $\Sigma_b = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2\\
b_2 & b_1
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, $w_1,w_2,b_1,b_2,\alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\circ$ is element by element matrix product.

Then I have the complex pdf describing the distribution of points $\lambda = x+iy$ given by

$$p(\lambda,\bar{\lambda},\epsilon) = -\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\Re\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{\lambda}}\sum_{m=1}^N\alpha_mG_m\right)$$

where $\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{\lambda}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right). $

I tried to solve this problem numerically and it seems that $p(x,y)$ is nonzero possible only in an ellipse region and $0$ outside this region. This means all of the points such that $p(x,y)$ is nonzero is located inside an ellipse.

But how to solve this problem analytically? I tried to start with
$$G_m = \begin{pmatrix}
r_m & \beta_m\\
\bar{\beta_m} & \bar{r_m}
\end{pmatrix}$$

and form set of equations based on entries of this matrix but it ends nowhere. Is there any hint for this problem?